# Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error message? The error pops up when I am trying to create the RENTAL table.

```
CREATE TABLE CAR_CLASS
(CAR_CLASS_ID INT(3) PRIMARY KEY,
CAR_CLASS CHAR(20),
RENTAL_RATE DECIMAL(4,2) );

CREATE TABLE CAR
(CAR_ID CHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
CAR_CLASS_ID INT(3),
CAR_COLOR CHAR(20),
FOREIGN KEY (CAR_CLASS_ID) REFERENCES CAR_CLASS(CAR_CLASS_ID) );

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_INFO
(CUSTOMER_ID CHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
CUSTOMER_FIRST CHAR(30),
CUSTOMER_LAST CHAR(30),
CUSTOMER_CC_NUMBER CHAR(16));


CREATE TABLE RENTAL
(RENTAL_ID INT(3) PRIMARY KEY,
RENTAL_DATE_OUT DATE,
RENTAL_DATE_IN DATE,
CAR_CLASS_ID INT(3),
CAR_ID CHAR(25),
CUSTOMER_ID CHAR(30),
FOREIGN KEY (CAR_CLASS_ID) REFERENCES CAR_CLASS(CAR_CLASS_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (CAR_ID) REFERENCES CAR(CAR_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_ID) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your other table is called CUSTOMER_INFO, while your foreign key references just CUSTOMER. Change your last CREATE TABLE to this:

```
CREATE TABLE RENTAL
(RENTAL_ID INT(3) PRIMARY KEY,
RENTAL_DATE_OUT DATE,
RENTAL_DATE_IN DATE,
CAR_CLASS_ID INT(3),
CAR_ID CHAR(25),
CUSTOMER_ID CHAR(30),
FOREIGN KEY (CAR_CLASS_ID) REFERENCES CAR_CLASS(CAR_CLASS_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (CAR_ID) REFERENCES CAR(CAR_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER_INFO(CUSTOMER_ID) );
```

Answer (score 0):

the name of the table is wrong while creating a RENTAL table.

Look at the last line of your code.

FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_ID).

instead of customer, it should be CUSTOMER_INFO.

All the best :)

Comment: OMG THANK YOU BOTH SO MUCH! I WAS GETTING CROSS-EYED LOOKING FOR THE MISTAKE AND FINALLY GAVE UP!